# SwiftUI Getting Unique Values from a Struct (from a JSON)

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm new to Swift and stuck on what could be a simple problem...

**Background:**

- I'm trying to build a recipe app that has different recipes for each day of the week (7 days)
- A json contains all the data in the hierarchy: *Days -> have multiple Recipes -> have multiple Ingredients*, where the ingredients have the following format:

  ```
       "ingredients": [
          {
              "item": "cereal",
              "amount": 1,
              "units": "cup(s)"
          },
          {
              "item": "milk",
              "amount": 0.2,
              "units": "L"
          }
       ]
  ```

**Desired Outcome:**

- What I'm trying to achieve is a shopping list that shows the unique list of all items that are needed for ALL recipes

**How far I got so far:**

The data is pulled from the json in this format which works:

```
struct Day: Hashable, Codable, Identifiable {

    //Breakfast
    var breakfastData: mealResponse
    //Dinner
    var dinnerData: mealResponse
    
    struct mealResponse: Hashable, Codable {
        struct IngredientResponse: Hashable, Codable {
            var item: String
            var amount: Double
            var units: String
        }
    }
}
```

Then I manage to get the full list of ingredients like this:

```
ForEach(userData.days, id: \.self) { day in
                ForEach(day.breakfastData.ingredients, id: \.self) {ingredient in
                    Text(ingredient.item)
                    }
                }
```

But this is not a unique list (it just goes through every day and lists ALL ingredients for the breakfast recipes in this case...)
Would be so grateful for some help on this - have literally spent weeks trying all sorts of things...

**Bonus:**

- The next step is then to show the sum of the "quantities" next to this unique list so the user knows how much of each ingredient s/he needs to make all the recipes in the json

Comment: Why don't you add `UUID` to your Day model with conforming `Identifiable` ?

Answer (score 0):

To get an array of all ingredients you can use `reduce` and work with a `Set` to only add unique ingredients

```
let allIngredients = Array(days.reduce(into: Set<String>()) {
    $0.formUnion($1.breakfastData.ingredients.map(\.item))
    $0.formUnion($1.dinnerData.ingredients.map(\.item))
})
```

Regarding the "bonus", first of all you should only ask one question at a time but secondly let me just say that this might be much harder than expected since different recipes might use different units for the same ingredients so you will have to use a common unit between them before you can add them together. Also in your example you have a cup of cereal but that is something you buy a box of so there is another problem

Comment: @lyfsgud, any feedback on this?